# How to prevent an arc when a device is plugged in

Tags: current, arc

I have a device that takes arcs when I connect the power plug. It uses 24V. The 24V source is far awar so a 47uF cap is at the input. Charging this large cap causes a big zap every time. A 10Ω series resistor helps, but the device takes ~200mA at peak load; 0.4W is a lot to burn off at the input.

Answer (score 3):

I had a very similar issue where there were a bunch of devices that could be connected and disconnected from a CAN plus 24 V power bus on the fly.  You want a cap local to the device because you can't trust the impedance of the 24 V line, but you also don't want to glitch the line and burn the connector contacts during plugging.

Here is how I dealt with this:

[image]

The 24 V from the can bus first goes thru diode D1.  While this does protect against accidental negative voltages, its main purpose is to protect the internal 24 V supply from sudden negative glitches on the 24 V bus.  This could happen, for example, if the 24 V accidentally got shorted elsewhere.  The reverse flow of current can cause trouble.

This is basically a soft-start circuit.  Q2 is the pass element that is slowly turned on to connect the internal 24V net to the external 24 V supply.  R2 turns on Q2, with D2 making sure the gate voltage stays within 12 V of the source to not hurt the FET.

When the voltage slope on 24V gets high enough, it causes enough current thru C2 to turn on Q3.  That turns on Q1, which tries to turn off the FET.  The net effect is that the rising slope of the voltage on the 24V net is limited.

The main slope-setting component is C2, which is used as a voltage slope to current converter in this case.  That current develops a voltage across R3, which is what ultimately causes the FET gate drive to be reduced.  R3 therefore also sets the slope regulation point, but keeping it at about the same as R4 is useful so that the fraction of C2 current going into the base of Q3 is negligible.  This provides reliable operation over a wide range of Q3 gains.

With the parts shown, the startup ramp takes about a couple 100 ms.  That works well in this application for the amount of capacitance on the 24V net.  There are other capacitors on that net at various points of use not shown in this schematic snippet.  No arcing can be seen when plugging the connector into P1.

Answer (score 2):

Probably the simplest way to do what you want is to use a thermistor with a negative temperature coefficient (NTC) that starts out with a relatively high resistance but rapidly drops as it self-heats due to the current flowing through it.

There are products specifically built to limit this type of inrush current, and a Google search will get you lots of information.

Here's an example, this manufacturer's website has lots of info on available products and how to choose them:

[Inrush Limiters](https://www.ametherm.com/?gclid=CNXRmY_9v9QCFQ9EfgodfEINyA)

Other possibilities are using a switch (MOSFET or relay for example) to short out a resistor once the inrush has passed.  This is possibly a better solution without ambient temperature variation and with less series resistance, but it's more complex and larger than the NTC.